# nginx upstream subdomain on the same server

Tags: nginx, configuration, dns, load-balancing

I am configuring Nginx load balance with Nginx upstream module, configuration as follow:

```
upstream load {
    server loadapi.example.com;
    server loadapi.anotherdomain.com down;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://load;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name loadapi.example.com;
    root /disk/projects/load/loadapi;
    index index.html index.htm index.shtml index.php;
    ...
    ...
    error_page  404               /404.html;
}
```

Notice that the `api.example.com` and `loadapi.example.com` are on the same server. `loadapi.anotherdomain.com` is resolved to another server which provides the same service.

Everything works fine with `loadapi.anotherdomain.com`, which are on another server.

But when I use the `loadapi.example.com` as the backend, it seems that Nginx cannot handle it correctly. I can get my service up and running on `loadapi.example.com`. But it is not working with the upstream.(look like Nginx cannot resolve the subdomain name correctly).

any advice? thx in advance.

Comment: Can you add the error / access log of Nginx during (or attempt of) an access?

Comment: @Adriano Martins Yes, I do add the access/error log in corresponding server block. And I found out that the `loadapi.example.com` is not being called. Instead another service is called.(nginx default vhost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nginx` uses the `Host` header to determine which `server` block to use to process a request.

When the request passes through the `proxy_pass http://load;` statement, the `Host` header is set to the value `load` by default.

To make `nginx` choose the `server` block containing the `server_name loadapi.example.com;` statement, it either needs to be the `default_server` server, or include the name `load` in its `server_name`, or set the `Host` header using:

```
proxy_set_header Host loadapi.example.com;
```

Of course, using `upstream` for load balancing means that both servers receive the same value for the `Host` header, and must both respond correctly to it.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) for more.

Comment: That means if I have multiple vhost domain name in another server, `loadapi.anotherdomain.com` and `anotherapi.anotherdomain.com`. Nginx can only match the default server_name in the other server?

Comment: Not at all. The server_name of each vhost can have any number of aliases. If you set the Host header to loadapi.example.com, simply add that name to the server_name statement of the appropriate vhost on the other server.